# Intercept Swarm/Forsquare check-in action

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which needs to provide user notifications when he enters specific places based on some criterias. I'm thinking of ways to make prediction about if user wants to visit this place or not and I thought that I can use information about `Forsquare`/`Swarm` check-ins. I'm almost sure that I can fetch check-in history using `Forsquare` API but can I intercept this action in real time?

Comment: Why not create your own Geofences and trigger whatever that needs to be done within your app?

Comment: AFAIK there may be no more then 100 geofences per user. Also simple detection the area entrance is not a problem. I'm just trying to find ways of detection algorithm improvement and also that user enters EXACTLY the place which I'm promoting with my app.